# Intuition behind connectedness = path connectedness in the complex numbers

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, connectedness

The 2-D reals are isomorphic to the complex numbers, correct?

So why is it that “connected” is equivalent to “path connected” in the complex numbers, but not in the 2-D reals (as exemplified by the [topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve))?  Couldn't we just construct a topologist’s sine curve in the complex numbers as well: that is, the collection of points that includes the origin $z=0$ as well as all points $z=x+iy$ in the complex plane where $(x,y) = (x, \sin(1/x)) : x \in (0,1] $?

I think there's some intuition behind this that I'm missing.

Comment: "So why is it that “connected” is equivalent to “path connected” in the complex numbers?" It isn't. Perhaps you are thinking of the result that an open connected set in $\mathbb C$ is path connected. Same is true of $\mathbb R^n$ for any $n.$

Comment: I doubt your claim "connected is equivalent to path-connected in the complex numbers", can you provide a reference for that?

Comment: Ah you're right -- I was misunderstanding -- the actual claim was what zhw wrote below -- that in the topology of the complex plane, an open set being path connected is equivalent to an open set being connected.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

The space $\Bbb R^2$ is connected and path connected. Of course, $\Bbb R^2$ has some subsets which, endowed with the subspace topology, are connected and not path-connected. The same is true for $\Bbb C$, since $\Bbb C$ and $\Bbb R^2$ are homeomorphic.

Answer (score 2):

so called "Domains" or (in German) "Gebiete" in $\Bbb C$ have the property that path-connectedness is equivalent to connectedness. These are **open** subsets of $\Bbb C$ and often serve as a domain for a differentiable function in complex function theory. So one often sees this in analysis text books. It's essentially due to $\Bbb C$ being locally convex (hence locally path-connected), which inherits to open subsets.

But the topologist's curve is a subspace of $\Bbb C \simeq \Bbb R^2$ as well, so your general assertion isn't correct.